# Evaluating the integral $I (k)= \int_\infty^0\frac{k}{x^2 +k^2}\ln x ~ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> $$\int_0^\infty\left(\dfrac{\pi}{1 + \pi^2x^2}- \dfrac{1}{1+x^2}\right)\ln x dx$$

Attempt:

$x \to \dfrac{1}{x}$

gives:

$\displaystyle\int_\infty^0 \left(\dfrac{\pi}{\pi^2+x^2}- \dfrac{1}{1+x^2}\right)\ln x  ~dx$

So its basically reduced to evaluating: $I (k)= \displaystyle\int_\infty^0\dfrac{k}{x^2 +k^2}\ln x ~dx$

For this I tried:

- Differentiation wrt k  using Lebnitz Rule
- Integration by parts

Both these methods don't seem to work because of the presence of messy inverse functions. Please let me know how to continue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can let $x= k t$ to find
$$ I(k) \equiv\int \limits_0^\infty \frac{-k \ln(x)}{k^2+x^2} \, \mathrm{d} x = \int \limits_0^\infty \frac{-\ln(t)}{1+t^2} \, \mathrm{d} t + \int \limits_0^\infty \frac{-\ln(k)}{1+t^2} \, \mathrm{d} t \, .$$
Your substitution $t \to \frac{1}{t}$ shows that the first integral vanishes and the second integral can be solved by a trigonometric substitution. In the end you should get 
$$ I(k) = -\frac{\pi}{2} \ln(k) \, . $$

Comment: @Abcd It is divergent at $k=0$ , as is $I(k)$ itself. Everywhere else it is finite and given by $I'(k) = - \frac{\pi}{2 k}$ .

Answer (score 2):

Here's a great way to proceed after substituting $x= kt$ :

$I(k) = \displaystyle \int_0^\infty \dfrac{\ln(kt)}{1+t^2} dt$

$\implies \dfrac{dI}{dk}=\dfrac 1k \displaystyle\int_0^\infty\dfrac{1}{1+t^2}$dt

$\implies \dfrac{dI}{dk}= -\dfrac 1k\dfrac{\pi}{2}$
$$\implies  \bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]
{I(k)= -\dfrac{\pi}{2}\ln k }$$